# Quantlib RiskFreeCurve

Tags: c++, quantlib

Following [this](https://www.implementingquantlib.com/2016/07/translating-python-to-cpp.html) document on how to port a `python` `QL` program to `C++`, I try:

```
auto cp = 'C';
auto k = 100.0;
auto u = make_shared<SimpleQuote>(100.0);
auto r = make_shared<SimpleQuote>(0.01);
auto sigma = make_shared<SimpleQuote>(0.20);
auto t = calendar.businessDaysBetween(d1, expiry) / cDays;

auto exercise = EuropeanExercise(expiry);
auto payoff = ('C' == cp ? PlainVanillaPayoff(Option::Call, k) :
                             PlainVanillaPayoff(Option::Put, k));

auto european_option = EuropeanOption(
    boost::make_shared<PlainVanillaPayoff>(payoff),
    boost::make_shared<EuropeanExercise>(exercise));

auto riskFreeCurve =
    make_shared<FlatForward>(0, TARGET(), Handle<Quote>(r), Actual360());
```

I get the following error:

```
qldate.cpp:49:58: error: no matching function for call to \u2018QuantLib::Handle<QuantLib::Quote>::Handle(std::shared_ptr<QuantLib::SimpleQuote>&)\u2019
     make_shared<FlatForward>(0, TARGET(), Handle<Quote>(r), Actual360());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
auto u = make_shared<SimpleQuote>(100.0);
```

Make sure you qualify the `boost` version:

```
auto u = boost::make_shared<SimpleQuote>(100.0);
```

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice